# on omxplayer how to change left/right arrow to seek 10 seconds instead of 30 seconds?

Tags: omxplayer

Is there any way to modify the arrow keys to seek to different time-jumps?  I'd rather have 10 seconds and 60 seconds jumps instead of the default 30 seconds and 600 seconds.

Comment: the source code is here https://github.com/popcornmix/omxplayer ........ start at `KeyConfig.cpp` near line 124 ....... search the source code for the keywords in  those lines ( ACTION_SEEK_...... )